# Selecting unique value from unequal character strings in R

Tags: arrays, r, character

I am writing a code to pull data from a database which removes item columns that contain all NAs.  I want R to tell give me the column name of the removed column.  I have newdat and newdat1, which is the data before and after removal of the columns that contain NA.  Thus, so far I have:

```
> name<-colnames(newdat)
> name
[1] "i5" "i4" "i2" "i3" "i1" "b4" "b3" "b2" "b1"
```

and

```
> name1<-colnames(newdat1)
> name1
[1] "b3" "i5" "i4" "i2" "b2" "b1" "i3" "i1"
```

Thus, I have two character strings of unequal length with 8 values that are the same and 1 that is unique to newdat1.  How can I extract this value?  I have tried variations of `unique` and `which` functions such as:

```
xnames<-name1[-which(name1==name)]
```

But I get an error because they are unequal lengths.  Please help!  Thank you.

Comment: Do you know `?setdiff`?

Comment: No I am not familiar with it, but I did just try using "name" and "name1" as its x and y arguments and it did not work.  Is there a better way to use it?

Comment: Two answers already demonstrate the use of `setdiff`. Just be aware of the differences in this small example: `x <- letters[1:3]; y <- letters[2:4]; setdiff(x, y); setdiff(y, x)`.

Comment: `setdiff` returns a value that includes both what was requested (items in name1 that are not in name) as well as its obverse (which was NOT requested). Unfortunately the one person to answer so far has chosen to deliver the obverse. And this is probably because the question was incorrectly stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try  :

```
 name[!(name %in% name1)]
```

As pointed out, if you want to go both ways (ie some might be in name1 but not name), you need the opposite:

```
name1[!(name1 %in% name)]
```

or to find all differences together:

```
c(name1[!(name1 %in% name)], name[!(name %in% name1)])
```

Comment: Unfortunately what was asked was impossible since there were no items that were unique to name1.

Comment: Yes I apologize I did name and name1 backwards, but the code worked.

Answer (score 2):

As @docendo discimus suggested, use `setdiff`:

```
> name <- c("i5", "i4", "i2", "i3", "i1", "b4", "b3", "b2", "b1")
> name1 <- c("b3", "i5", "i4", "i2", "b2", "b1", "i3", "i1")
> setdiff(name, name1)
[1] "b4"
```